# Why are Unicode character in RTF followed by \'3f?

Tags: unicode, rtf

If you look at the way RTF encodes Unicode, it always follows a Unicode character by a 0x3f character, which is a question mark:

```
\u20181\'3f\u20182\'3f\u20183\'3f\u30340\'3f
```

Does anyone here know why it does this? Is it just to maintain compatibility with pre-Unicode RTF readers?

Comment: IIRC it's a replacement character so that platforms that don't support Unicode will render the replacement one. The correct replacement string isn't always `?` though but the closest in the current code page and can be multiple characters

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Character_encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\'3f` represents a hexadecimal character.  In this case (with Python's help), a question mark.  It depends on the current code page selected which is not shown in the RTF provided, but whatever it was didn't support these characters in that code page:

```py
>>> chr(0x3f)
'?'
```

The Unicode characters are `仕他仗的` (again with Python's help):

```py
>>> chr(20181)+chr(20182)+chr(20183)+chr(30340)
'仕他仗的'
```

In a Word document I generated and saved as RTF, `\u-26004\'c2\'ed\u20811\'bf\'cb` was the two characters `马克`. `c2 ed` and `bf cb` was a chinese-encoded equivalent selected by `\fcharset134` earlier in the document.

```py
>>> chr(-26004 & 0xffff) + chr(20811)  # 0xffff mask needed to limit 2s complement to 16 bits.
'马克'
>>> bytes.fromhex('c2 ed bf cb').decode('chinese')
'马克'
```

For more information read the [RTF specification](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/Archive_References/%5bMSFT-RTF%5d.pdf):

Comment: Would you say then that I should either parse \u### OR \'##? It sounds like the latter is no longer needed.

Comment: I don’t know your exact requirements, but the specification has some example RTF readers.  The \u syntax is the direct result of decoding the data bytes.

Comment: My goal is just to parse the RTF and be done with it. I don't care about supporting little-used code pages from decades past. The RTF I'm seeing e.g. produced by LibreOffice has both the \u format and the \' characters. I'm inferring that if there is \u then I can safely ignore the \'. Is that right? Also, the \'3f that I'm seeing is not a Chinese character even though it follows a Chinese unicode character.

Comment: Yes you can ignore. The '3f is a ? And means the active code page in your document doesn’t support the character.

Comment: What intersting though is that when I give this to LibreOffice, it does parse it as abcB: {\rtf1\pard\'61\'62\'63\u66\'64\par} and it ignores the "d" character. Thus it seems they are using the same reasoning, that if there is a \u###, then it stops reading the \'##.